# Spectrum of formal series ring on several variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[[x]]=\{(x),(0)\}$, can I generalize it for formal series on several variables? $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[[x_1,...,x_n]]=(x_1,...,x_n)$?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The zero ideal is also there, sorry for the mistake..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\ge2$ Spec$\,\Bbb C[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ has more than one point.
It is a local ring, with maximal ideal $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$,
but has many other prime ideals, for instance
$(x_1)$, $(x_1,x_2)$ etc. It is an example of a [regular local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring)
of dimension $n$.